# This simple XHTML will not validate. What is the problem?

Tags: xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<title>My Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css"/>

</head>
<body>

<div>

<h1>Heading One</h1>
<p class="para1">Paragraph One</p>

<h3>Heading Two</h3>
<p>Paragraph Two</p>

<h3>Heading Three</h3>
<p>Paragraph Three</p>

<br />
<a href="Lab1Page2.html">Link One</a>
<br />
<a href="Lab1Page3.html">Link Two</a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the validator????

Comment: I have spent two hours trying everything. I cant find a single xhtml document online that validates strict. I must be missing something. What could be the problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: the validation service has a verbose error output function that will tell you which line(s) the problem(s) are in. http://validator.w3.org/check

Answer (score 9):

```
<p>Paragraph Three<p>
```

That is the problem.

Edit: the other `<p>` should obviously be `</p>`

Edit 2: Noticed a larger problem: The XML definition or whatever-it's-called should always be on the first line. If I recall correctly.

Edit 3: Yup, I checked. W3 validator tells this:

> **XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document**

Comment: Regarding Edit 2: If I remember correctly, IE will fail to set Standards Mode when anything is between the beginning of the document and the doctype. Best idea is to leave the XML declaration out, I read somewhere.

Comment: But the XML declaration is necessary.

Comment: (I fixed the <p>)

It says:

1 error, 3 warnings

No Character Encoding Found! Falling back to UTF-8.

Unable to Determine Parse Mode!

No Character encoding declared at document level

Line 1, Column 1: end of document in prolog.

Answer (score 2):

Run it through the W3C validator, and it will point you right at the problems: http://validator.w3.org/

Specifically:

This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Must go at the very top of the document, not below the DOCTYPE.

And you've forgotten a '/' on the closing p tag here:

```
<p>Paragraph Three<p>
```

Once those problems are corrected, it validates just fine.

Comment: This man is correct. He said what I did but in a less confusing way and fixed both problems at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it through the [W3C checker here](http://validator.w3.org/) (click on the "direct input" tab and copy/paste) and it will give you very specific feedback as to what doesn't validate

Comment: I fixed all the problems that people mentioned. The validator says its good if i paste my work in it but if i choose the upload option it says it still has errors. Why would it do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<title>My Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css"/>

</head> <body>

<div>

<h1>Heading One</h1> <p class="para1">Paragraph One</p>

<h3>Heading Two</h3> <p>Paragraph Two</p>

<h3>Heading Three</h3> <p>Paragraph Three</p>

<br /> <a href="Lab1Page2.html">Link One</a> <br /> <a href="Lab1Page3.html">Link Two</a>

</div>

</body> </html>
```

The   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` must be the first line in the XML document. 
See the XML Specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/

Answer (score 0):

To pass XHTML validator  [http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) you need to change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335275/7339351)